# OpenCV, How to pass parameters into cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create function?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.3

I'm trying to create MEDIANFLOW tracker with OpenCV3.3 using opencv-python with Python3.6. I need to pass some arguments into the constructor according to this page of OpenCV [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dd/dd9/structcv_1_1TrackerMedianFlow_1_1Params.html).

The problem is I don't know how to pass available arguments into this function correctly? I wasn't able to find any information about it.

What I do (and it works):

```
tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
```

What I want to do:

```
tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create(maxLevel=3)
```

But it doesn't work and gives me an error:

```
SystemError: <built-in function TrackerMedianFlow_create> returned NULL without setting an error
```

Could you help?

Comment: Note that the documentation you linked is the constructor *for the params* structure. I don't have 3.3 to test how to do it, but you need to instantiate a `TrackeMedianFlowr::Params()` object, and then pass *that* object into `TrackerMedianFlow_create()`. Check the [docs for `TrackerMedianFlow()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d7/d86/classcv_1_1TrackerMedianFlow.html) to see that the constructor accepts only a `TrackerMedianFlow::Params()` object.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52026745/5294258

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I search the intermediate code generated by cmake/make when compiling the OpenCV 3.3 for Python 3.5, just cannot find the methods to set the parameters for `cv2.TrackerXXX`.

In `modules/python3/pyopencv_generated_funcs.h`, I find this function:

```
static PyObject* pyopencv_cv_TrackerMedianFlow_create(PyObject* , PyObject* args, PyObject* kw)
{
    using namespace cv;

    Ptr<TrackerMedianFlow> retval;

    if(PyObject_Size(args) == 0 && (kw == NULL || PyObject_Size(kw) == 0))
    {
        ERRWRAP2(retval = cv::TrackerMedianFlow::create());
        return pyopencv_from(retval);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

This is to say, you cann't pass any parameter to `cv::TrackerMedianFlow_create()`.

In `modules/python3/pyopencv_generated_types.h`, I find this one:

```
static PyGetSetDef pyopencv_TrackerMedianFlow_getseters[] =
{
    {NULL}  /* Sentinel */
};
```

This to say, you have no way to change the parameters for Python wrapper by default, Unless you modified the source code and recompile it.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it seems like you say. I'll find other ways.

Answer (score 4):

You can customize Tracker parameters via FileStorage interface.

```
import cv2

# write
tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
tracker.save('params.json')

# write (another way)
fs = cv2.FileStorage("params.json", cv2.FileStorage_WRITE)
tracker.write(fs)
fs.release()

# read
tracker2 = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
fs = cv2.FileStorage("params.json", cv2.FileStorage_READ)
tracker2.read(fs.getFirstTopLevelNode())
```