# Python says that "TrackerMedianFlow_create()" is no longer an attribute of cv2, Has the Library been updated?

Tags: python, opencv

Python says that TrackerMedianFlow_create() is no longer an attribute of cv2.

I've looked here but it's not the same: [OpenCV, How to pass parameters into cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723349/opencv-how-to-pass-parameters-into-cv2-trackermedianflow-create-function)
I've asked on several discord servers without success.
I've copied this code directly from my textbook with ctrl + c so it should be exact.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("../data/traffic.mp4")
_, frame = cap.read()

bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False, True)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
status_tracker = tracker.init(frame, bbox)
fps = 0

while True:
    status_cap, frame = cap.read()
    if not status_cap:
        break

    if status_tracker:
        timer = cv2.getTickCount()
        status_tracker, bbox = tracker.update(frame)

    if status_tracker:
        x, y, w, h = [int(i) for i in bbox]
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 15)
        fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer);
        cv2.putText(frame, "FPS: %.0f" % fps, (0, 80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3.5, (0, 0, 0), 8);
    else:
        cv2.putText(frame, "Tracking failure detected", (0, 80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3.5, (0,0,255), 8)

    cv2.imshow("MedianFlow tracker", frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if k == 27: 
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My line that causes the problem is:

```
tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
```

Up until there the code runs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Documents/E-Books/Comp Vision/opencv3computervisionwithpythoncookbook_ebook/OpenCV3ComputerVisionwithPythonCookbook_Code/Chapter04/myPart5.py", line 11, in <module>
    tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'TrackerMedianFlow_create'
```

I expected it to work without an error.

Answer (score 2):

for opencv 4.5.1 user

opencv-contrib-python

```
import cv2
cv2.legacy_TrackerMedianFlow()
```

Answer (score 1):

`TrackerMedianFlow` is a [module within the opencv-contrib package](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/tracking/src), and does not come standard with the official OpenCV distribution. You will need to install the opencv-contrib package to access `TrackerMedianFlow_create()`

Per the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/), you should uninstall the package without the additional modules and proceed to reinstall opencv with the additional modules you need.

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Comment: from 4.5.1, they are put in legacy

Answer (score -1):

It has been installed opencv-contrib-python-4.5.4.60 version,Again AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'TrackerMedianFlow_create',what is the reason

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32522281)