# How to use setInitialMask on TrackerCSRT?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using `TrackerCSRT` for object tracking in a video, and currently I use the init method on the tracker to set the `region of interest`

```
tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()
tracker.init(frame, region_of_interest)
```

The region of interst include my object, but it also include irrelevant pixels from the background or other objects.

I would like to use a mask to refine which pixels I'm interested in. Looking over the documentation, I can see method [`setInitialMask` on the `C++` version](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/da2/classcv_1_1TrackerCSRT.html#aff417551954c23b3261733a9afd1e336), but I cannot find the equivalent method in the `Python` wrapper.

**How do I set a mask in `TrackerCSRT` on `openCV` for `Python`?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i made a [Pull Request](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/pull/1737) to enable use of cv::TrackerCSRT::setInitialMask() for Python and Java.

additionally may the following python code will be useful to play with params.

```
tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()
tracker.save("default_csrt.xml") // saves default values of the Tracker
                                    you can rename default_csrt.xml-> custom_csrt.xml 
                                    and change values in it and use it load params

fs = cv2.FileStorage("custom_csrt.xml",cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)
fn = fs.getFirstTopLevelNode()
tracker.read(fn)
```

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, you can't.  But you could do it if you are prepared to rebuild OpenCV.

The creation of Python bindings for OpenCV C++ modules is controlled by markup in the C++ files, as documented [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html). At the time of writing, the [C++ declaration of setInitialMask()](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/874edea9f4df4b60396641573b130355cf62555c/modules/tracking/include/opencv2/tracking/tracker.hpp#L1525) does not have the markup which causes a Python binding to be created for it, so it is inaccessible.  I expect that is because the TrackerCSRT implementation is only a few months old, and that Python bindings will follow as it matures.

However, if you are prepared to rebuild OpenCV on your system (which can be a little challenging if you haven't done it before), making setInitialMask() accessible from Python should be as simple as adding the CV_WRAP macro to that declaration (as explained in the above documentation) and rebuilding.

There are quite a few guides online for how to build OpenCV, but since I haven't done this myself in a while and the methods are somewhat platform dependent, I won't recommend one.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of `setInitialMask` but in python you can select your region of interest using `cv2.selectROI()` method.

A [blog post on tracking objects in a video can be found here](https://www.learnopencv.com/multitracker-multiple-object-tracking-using-opencv-c-python/) along with relevant code in a step-by-step approach.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't.

Just complementing @chungzuwalla answer, the tracker c++ code only uses mask if you set `params.use_segmentation`, but the Tracker python interface does not let you set params.

Comment: params.use_segmentation is true by default. you can see the way of setting params in my answer.